# How to group qualified layouts by name in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio Project_A and Project_B both contain the following layouts:

```
res/layout/xyzzy.xml
res/layout-land/xyzzy.xml
res/layout-sw768dp-port/xyzzy.xml
res/layout-sw768dp-land/xyzzy.xml
```

However, they appear in their respective Project trees differently:

In project_A I see only "res/layout/xyzzy.xml(4)"
(i.e. the 4 variants are grouped nicely together and the 3 variant sub-folders do not show in the tree)

In Project_B I see all 4 qualified sub-folders and each must be expanded to access the individual layout variants.

How do I make Project_B behave like Project_A?

I realize this is a parameterisation issue and not a programming issue. But I am dealing with a 100+ layouts and this issue is slowing me down badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your project view types are different, Change the project view type to Android in project_B you should see the variants grouped by name.

Comment: Bravo and thank-you. I looked everywhere but under my nose!